# How to get categories detail from product item added in cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to get categories details like name and id from the product item which are added the in cart.

please help out in getting data of checkout cart product and i want to use it in my custom module every time i try to getting data it gives me null by using

```
$this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
```

Comment: Try using `$this->_cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();`.

Comment: Try but getting null

Comment: getAllVisibleItems() might get you what you need

Comment: do this one also

Comment: `$this->create('\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface')->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();` try this.

Comment: Null results on var_dump